# Is there a way in .Net 5 to store the private key in the TPM when we import a pfx into the Windows Certificate Store?

Tags: .net-5, private-key, tpm

I know that we can do it with `certutil -csp Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider" -importpfx` but wondering if we can in .Net 5

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179409/how-to-generate-a-unique-and-uncopyable-vpn-certificate-key-for-a-specific-clien/179422#179422 this might help you.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4f21c8fb-501f-42f0-b17b-0e75bf237a29/generate-and-store-certificate-key-in-tpm also have a loot at this article.

Comment: @MahmudulHasan thanks for those links but I was wanting to know if it could be done with .Net 5